# breakpoint after page reload

Tags: javascript, firebug, breakpoints, google-chrome-devtools

I need to stop on breakpoint after page reloading. I put a breakpoint in code but after reload  it's being disabled.

putting

```
debugger;
```

in code works fine.

But I was wondering if there is a way to do it in firebug or chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be you have parameters in the url of the page that changes when your reload.

`http://website.com/page.html?stamp=20120516103456`

You then load a new page each time you refresh.
That may explain why your breakpoint disappear.

Comment: Thank you, @Mic. I dont have any parameters

Comment: if you type in the console `window.location.reload()` the breakpoint disappears too?

Comment: yes, it didappears. maybe I am doing it wrong somehow. I am not familliar with any debugger settings. I just put a break point then I reload a page and there's no breakpoint on that place..

Comment: if you use chrome dev tool, when you click the line number, you should see a kind of dark blue arrow. If the arrow is light blue, it means the breakpoints are deactivated. It is an icon at the top right, that toggle all breakpoints.

Comment: There is parameter in js file attachment. So your answer is right! I can't use breakpoints in this case, right? Or there's a way to use breakpoints when params are used?

Comment: May be put your breakpoint in the HTML, or another resource that has no parameters.

Comment: The parameters changing is exactly the reason firebug is doing this to me, and it's unacceptable!  Chrome Dev Tools do NOT do this %$#@ to me!