# Devtools Breakpoints Behavior Inconsistent

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I've been using breakpoints in Devtools for a long time, and have had little issue.  Lately I've experienced breakpoints not sticking after refresh or when I refresh only one of the breakpoints set will persist.  Or sometimes the breakpoint will hit, but the breakpoint will have been removed.

Has anyone been experiencing this or have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: If the URL of the script changes, the breakpoints won't stick. And since breakpoints are associated with line numbers, if you modify the script and code moves around, the breakpoints may be on the wrong lines.

Comment: Yeah I've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620741/breakpoint-after-page-reload, but this is happening when files aren't changed, and the url is not changed.

Comment: Yes I experience such issues. I just restart the devtool.

Comment: Make sure the url of the SCRIPT (not the page!) hasn't changed.  Look in the Network tab of devtools.  In my dev environment (IntelliJ) all assets get a cache-busting timestamp attached to the asset url.